# File not found error when uploading file with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I want to upload a file with symfony, but I always get an error when submitting my form.

This is my entity code:

```
 public function rootPath($directory) {
    return $this->getUploadRootDir($directory) . '/' . User::cleanFilename($this->file->getClientOriginalName());
}

public function getWebPath($directory) {

    return $this->getUploadDir($directory) . '/' . User::cleanFilename($this->file->getClientOriginalName());
}

public function getUploadDir($directory) {
    return $this->user->getDir() . '/' . $this->user->getDirectoryName() . '/' . $directory;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir($directory) {

    return $this->user->getRootDir() . '/' . $this->user->getDirectoryName() . '/' . $directory;
}

public function upload($directory) {
    // la propriété « file » peut être vide si le champ n'est pas requis
    if (null === $this->file) {

        return;
    }

    $this->filename = User::cleanFilename($this->file->getClientOriginalName());
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir($directory), $this->filename);

    // $this->url = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    //$this->filename=$this->getWebPath($directory);

    $result = $this->rootPath($directory);
    $this->file = null;
    return $result;
}
```

And this is what symfony return:

```
 Message    Origin  Cause
Le fichier n'a pas été trouvé.  file    Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.file = file3.csv
```

I tried several times but I always get the same problem.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Symfony2 cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) now suggest to try https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle, it is simple to integrate and the documentation is pretty good

Comment: Maybe you've permission problems on your server? The file is getting uploaded first to the tmp folder i guess. Maybe there is something wrong. Maybe the destination folder needs also the exact permissions. Try it with cmod -R 777 on your upload folder to test. But this permission is not for production!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved,

I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  and then the problem has been resolved